Database lookup in datatool fails for dynamically extracted key
Please see the MWE below:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testkeymatch.csv}
Key,ID,Name
k1,123,John
k2,456,Jane
k3,789,Mary
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV data
\DTLloaddb{data}{testkeymatch.csv}

% Extract the key 
\def\extractKey#1{%
  % Extract the part between the underscore and dot
  \StrBetween{#1}{_}{.}[\extractedKey]%
  \extractedKey
}

% For key matching
\def\findKeyInfo#1\end{%
  \xDTLassignfirstmatch{data}{Key}{#1}{%
    % Assign values to temporary macros
    \theID=ID,%
    \theName=Name}%
  % Output the result
  \theID, \theName%
}

\begin{document}

% This works for fixed key
k1: \findKeyInfo k1\end

\bigskip

% Dynamic key
\def\f{Prefix_k2.tex}
\def\key{\extractKey{\f}}
Extracted key: \key

k2 (dynamic):

% This produces error
\findKeyInfo\key\end

% This does not work as well 
\expandafter\findKeyInfo\key\end

\bigskip

% This works
\def\key{k3}
k3: \findKeyInfo\key\end 

\end{document}

The first and third case works. But the second case for the dynamically generated key produces this error:

! Undefined control sequence.
\@dtlgetrowindex ...@col@elt@w #4\db@col@elt@end@ 
                                                  \db@col@id@w #3\db@col@id@...
l.49 \findKeyInfo\key\end


Maybe, this has something to do with the type of return argument, \extractedKey, but I can not be sure. I searched the documentation for xstring, but failed to find anything indicative. Somehow, I am missing it. Naive assumption says that this is a macro. But the last case contradicts this.

You must to create \extractKey expandable:
\def\extractKey #1{\expandafter\extractKeyA #1_.\end}
\def\extractKeyA #1_#2.#3\end{#2}

and use \edef\key:
\def\f{Prefix_k2.tex}
\edef\key{\extractKey{\f}}

Note, that the macro \StrBetween isn't expandable.
If you will get the \f from \jobname or something similar then you will do more work because the contents of \f will include tokens with catcode 12. But this is not the subject of your question here.
If you want to manipulate with \jobname of similar outputs, then I suggest to re-catode it to the normal catcodes before using macros shown above. You can do this:
\edef\f{\jobname} % you have `\f` macro with catcodes 12
\scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\f\expandafter{\f}}
% now, you have \f with normal catcodes.

\scantokens is an eTeX primitive that runs the token processor again to its argument with currently set category codes.
From the relevant literature: \scantokens⟨expandafters⟩{⟨text⟩} re-tokenizes ⟨text⟩ using the actual tokenizer setting. The behavior is the same as when writing ⟨text⟩ to a virtual file and reading this file immediately.

Actually, I will get the value of \f from \currfilename, as rightly deduced by you. Do you want to provide a guideline on how best to handle this? I am already facing the issues.

OK, I added my suggestion what to do with catcodes 12.

Thanks. It works. Perhaps, you want to (i) remove the _ and . from {\expandafter\extractKeyA #1_.\end} and (ii) add some explanatory notes on how actually \scantokens works in the given context. Then, I should proceed to accept the answer which should be useful for others as well.

@Masroor (i) the _.\end is here for case if the given string doesn't contain _ followed by a text and by ..  The macro doesn't crash in this case but returns empty string (which is between _ and . written explicitly in the macro). (ii) \scantokens is eTeX primitive which runs the token processor again to its argument with currently set category codes. You can read about it for example in my text "TeX in a Nutshell"  http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf . Sorry, I cannot explain basic TeX features in all my answers.

The first trick is beauty on its own. The second point is concisely explained in the mentioned text. I am taking the liberty of copying it here.

You seem to have tried to implement a kind of 'result value' in the macro \extractKey by putting \extractedKey at the end. However, while this works in terms of outputting the value to the document, it is not a value that you can use as input for another command. A macro in LaTeX doesn't have a result, it just has an expansion, which contains everything in the macro.
So when you do \findKeyInfo\key\end, what you actually do is:
\xDTLassignfirstmatch{data}{Key}{
\StrBetween{Prefix_k2.tex}}{_}{.}[\extractedKey]%
  \extractedKey
}

which in turn will contain the full implementation of \StrBetween that performs very complex unexpandable operations.
This is not the kind of input that \xDTLassignfirstmatch expects or can handle, it needs a raw value or a macro that, without complications, can be expanded to a raw value.
This is the exact reason that xstring provides the optional result argument. This is the macro that you should use as input for the datatool macro:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testkeymatch.csv}
Key,ID,Name
k1,123,John
k2,456,Jane
k3,789,Mary
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV data
\DTLloaddb{data}{testkeymatch.csv}

% Extract the key 
\def\extractKey#1{%
  % Extract the part between the underscore and dot
  \StrBetween{#1}{_}{.}[\extractedKey]%
}

% For key matching
\def\findKeyInfo#1\end{%
  \xDTLassignfirstmatch{data}{Key}{#1}{%
    % Assign values to temporary macros
    \theID=ID,%
    \theName=Name}%
  % Output the result
  \theID, \theName%
}

\begin{document}

% This works for fixed key
k1: \findKeyInfo k1\end

\bigskip

% Dynamic key
\def\f{Prefix_k2.tex}
\extractKey{\f}
Extracted key: \extractedKey

k2 (dynamic):

% This works now too
\findKeyInfo\extractedKey\end

\bigskip

% This works
\def\key{k3}
k3: \findKeyInfo\key\end 

\end{document}

Result:

